# How to find Target of ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a contractor working on code that has been created/changed by 5 contractors prior to me over the last 5 to 8 years. It is an ASP.NET MVC 5.2 project built on .Net Framework 4.5.2.

Microsoft doesn't seem to give me a good way to locate the target. Take this snippet of code for example in the **EmployeeController.cs** file:

```cs
[HttpPost, ActionName("LoginConfirmations")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginConfirmations(Login employee)
{
    TempData["email"] = employee.Email;
    TempData["password"] = employee.Password;

    return RedirectToAction("ViewEmployeeConfirmation");
}
```

I can't seem to find anything called `ViewEmployeeConfirmation`, `EmployeeConfirmation`, or `ViewEmployee` using a text search.

Neither the Model nor the View folders seem to have this exact route (I have been placing break points at likely spots in the code, but they are not being hit).

How do I determine where `ViewEmployeeConfirmation` is routing to?

Comment: For example, try to use [`var url = Url.Action("ViewEmployeeConfirmation");`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) inside the `LoginConfirmations()` action method and the `url` will points to the `\controller\action` you want to known.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` redirection to a _method_ on the current controller (method maybe from a derived controller).  You'll have to identify what that method does to determine where the HTML is since it seems apparent that it's displaying non-stardard routing template/html.

Comment: Does the redirect work? If not, the action method might have been renamed. If it's under source control the commit history could have the old name somewhere. If the redirect works then it could be in a base class.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, the redirect works fine. I just struggle with finding the targets of calls like this. I can't right click and go to definition, and a text search doesn't work either. Where is it going?

Comment: If you replace `"ViewEmployeeConfirmation"` with `nameof(ViewEmployeeConfirmation)`, does it compile? If yes, then you can go to its definition.